Accelerated Excel Conditional Loop Clear Contents
I'm using the following simple macro to clear the column of cells in front of contacts for if they've been selected.
The contacts are broken up into categories delineated by a title row and therefore I need it to be conditional, so those title block cells aren't cleared, as they're used for sorting and other various aspects.
The problem is that I have over 7,000 contacts and although this macro works, it takes 15+ minutes to run.  Is there a better coding I can use to accelerate this process?
Sub ClearSelected()
a = MsgBox("WARNING: This will Clear all selected or invited contacts.  Wait for notification that the operation is complete.  Continue?", 4)
If a = 7 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 4 To LastRow
If Cells(i, Range("CompanyName").Column).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Or Cells(i, 
        Range("CompanyName").Column).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZY" Then
   Cells(i, Range("Invited").Column).ClearContents
End If
Next i

MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub

Update:
Since it seems faster to figure an if-statement than clearing the contents, I added in another condition that skips the cell if already clear.
It shortened the duration depending on how many cells need to be cleared.  Under a normal situation, it shortened the time about 5-7 minutes.
For i = 4 To LastRow
If Cells(i, Range("CompanyName").Column).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Or 
    Cells(i, Range("CompanyName").Column).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZY" Then
    If Cells(i, Range("Invited").Column).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, Range("Invited").Column).ClearContents
    End If
End If
Next i


Have you checked the value of LastRow? The UsedRange may be bigger than you think.

Switch off during run Application.ScreenUpdating and collect ranges and clear only at the end of the For...Next loop. These generally shortens the runtime.

Thank you for the suggestions.  LastRow reports correctly and tried turning off ScreenUpdating but it still took 15 minutes.

Is this the entire code or is there something else by any chance? (it takes seconds to run as is on my machine). Also, are the cells you clear linked to any formulas that could trigger a recalculation when the content is deleted?

Is your If logic correct? Seems like that would trigger ClearContents for any value... Did you mean And not Or ?

This is all of the code.  There are other formulas but can't see how deleting this info would cause a re-calc but definitely a valid point.  Yes I want it to clear the cell completely regardless of what information is in the cell except with the title rows I note.

There is a lot of information stored in this file.  Overall it's 21mb and heavy on macros.  It sounds like there isn't a more simple way for me to do this.

That's a huge file. If anything, the problem is likely not with this code, but something else in the file. Are there any worksheet change events associated with this sheet? If yes, you should turn it off (Application.EnableEvents = False) (remember to turn it back on at the end of the script)

Gave the EnableEvents a whirl and surprisingly it increased the time by a couple of minutes.

Are there any events attached to the sheet being updated by your macro?

No, its just a simple database but with a lot of information.

What cell value would not pass your Or'ed tests?  If x <> A Or x<> B Then - no value of x can be both =A and =B so one of those will always be true...

Speed Up Code By Introducing Arrays

This will replace any formulas with values in the destination (Invited) column.
I have assumed the named ranges are in the workbook containing this code (ThisWorkbook) while the sheet name could be different each time.

Option Explicit

Sub ClearInvitedColumn()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Clear ""Invited"" Column"
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 4
    Const COMPANY_RANGE_NAME As String = "CompanyName"
    Const INVITED_NAME As String = "Invited"
    Dim NOT_CRITERIA() As Variant:
    NOT_CRITERIA = VBA.Array("ZZZZZZZZZ", "ZZZZZZZZY")
    
    ' Ask the user to continue.
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    Answer = MsgBox("" _
         & "WARNING: This will clear all selected or invited contacts. " _
         & "Wait for the notification that the operation is complete. Continue?", _
         vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
    
    If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the ranges and return their values in arrays.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sColumn As Long, dColumn As Long
    
    With Application.Range(COMPANY_RANGE_NAME)
        Set ws = .Worksheet
        sColumn = .Column
        dColumn = ws.Range(INVITED_NAME).Column
    End With
        
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = LastRow - FIRST_ROW + 1
    If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range, sData() As Variant, dData() As Variant
    
    Set srg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, sColumn)).Resize(RowsCount)
    Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(dColumn)
    
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dData(1, 1) = drg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
        dData = drg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the arrays and for each mismatch
    ' in the source array (against the criteria), clear
    ' the corresponding value in the destination array.
    
    Dim CriteriaUpperLimit As Long: CriteriaUpperLimit = UBound(NOT_CRITERIA)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, Company As String, IsCompanyFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Company = CStr(sData(r, 1))
        IsCompanyFound = True
        For c = 0 To CriteriaUpperLimit
            If StrComp(Company, NOT_CRITERIA(c), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' =
                IsCompanyFound = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If IsCompanyFound Then dData(r, 1) = Empty
    Next r

    ' Return the values from the destination array in the destination range.

    Application.EnableEvents = False ' Not sure if that's necessary!?
        drg.Value = dData
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Share some feedback.
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Invited column cleared.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub


I was about to post this answer.  I tested it on some made up data, it takes < 1s to run.

Minor suggestions: 1) place the code to restore Application properties in a Error Handler, so they are not left in a disabled state if an error occurs. 2) if the issue with overwriting formula is a concern use dData(1, 1) = drg.Formula2 and drg.Formula2 = dData

@chrisneilsen Long time no see. Thanks for your feedback and suggestions. 1) Although I can't see what could go wrong, I would even go a step further and say "Always place... occurs even when you know nothing can go wrong because you don't." How I forgot about 2) is a mystery. If you wrote an answer, I would like you to post it. I'm sure others would too.

I won't be posting my answer because it was functionally identical to yours! (and I've binned it).  As to possible errors, one is an error value in the CustomerName column.   Another is if the Invited cells are protected.   Bottom line: don't trust people to supply sanitized data.

Suggestions for improvement:
Sub ClearSelected()
    'Declare your variables
    Dim ans, ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, cpyCol As Long, invCol As Long
    
    ans = MsgBox("WARNING: This will Clear all selected or invited contacts.  " & vbLf & _
         "Wait for notification that the operation is complete.  Continue?", _
         vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
    If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub 'user didn't click Yes
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    cpyCol = Range("CompanyName").Column 'get these once...
    invCol = Range("Invited").Column
    
    'this is better than using `UsedRange`
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cpyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'make sure calculation gets turned back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'speed up
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For i = 4 To lastrow
        v = ws.Cells(i, cpyCol).Value 'read cell once...
        If v <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" And v <> "ZZZZZZZZY" Then 'assume you meant `And` here?
           ws.Cells(i, invCol).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Complete")
    
haveError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub


Thank you for the suggestion but I tried it and it took much longer.  I had let it go on for 45 min before shutting it down.

Updated my answer to include setting calculation to manual.  If that doesn't work then there's something odd with your workbook which we can't see...
